# What are some approaches to making this organic shape?

Tags: modeling

I've been taking a stab and modelling organic shapes and came across this one image I am looking to recreate. I'm able to model the bottom piece from a cylinder and extruding it. Went about this process as if I was making a frog's feet.

Now the part that I am stuck on is the top part. I've tried starting from a square and using subsurf mods to create a sphere that I then manipulated into one of the bean-looking shapes. The results haven't been the best so I wanted to reach out to the community and see what are some other ways I can potentially go about creating the top shape. I've thought about sculpting the entire piece but feel I feel there must be a simpler method that I just haven't thought about.

Thank you!

[image: A trail shape i've been working on]  [image: Image i'm looking to recreate!]

Comment: You could begin with metaballs then sculpt, but if you want a clean topology you'll need to retopologize afterwards

Comment: Could try some spheres with lattice modifiers on them, once happy with the basic shape, join them together then sculpt the joints smooth